# How to text to columns in pandas and create new columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file as show below, the names column has names separated with commas, I want to spilt them on comma and append them to new columns and create the same csv, similar to the text to columns in excel, the problem is some rows have random number of names.

```
| Address | Name               |
| 1st st  | John, Smith        |
|2nd st.  | Andrew, Jane, Aaron|
```

my pandas code look something like this

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df1['Name'] = df1['Name'].str.split(',', expand=True)
df1.to_csv('results.csv',index=None)
```

offcourse this doesn't work because columns must be same length as key. The expected output is

```
| Address | Name  |     |      |
| 1st st  | John  |Smith|      |
|2nd st.  | Andrew| Jane| Aaron|
```

Comment: Is it the maximum in a row 2 commas? If then you can split into 3 columns based on ```,``` -> ```df1[['Name1','Name2','Name3']] = df1.Name.str.split(',' ,expand =True)``` and then ```df1.drop('Name',axis=1,inplace = True)```

Comment: the max names in some rows are almost 15 but can vary, the problem is I want to make it generic enough that it shouldnt matter. I dont want to hardcode the column names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

count the max number of commas, then accordingly assign to new columns.

```
max_commas = df['name'].str.split(',').transform(len).max()
df[[f'name_{x}' for x in range(max_commas)]] = df['name'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

input df:

```
      col                        name
0  1st st                 john, smith
1  2nd st          andrew, jane, aron
2  3rd st  harry, philip, anna, james
```

output:

```
      col                        name  name_0  name_1 name_2 name_3
0  1st st                 john, smith    john   smith   None   None
1  2nd st          andrew, jane, aron  andrew    jane   aron   None
2  3rd st  harry, philip, anna, james   harry  philip   anna  james
```

Comment: this looks a pretty good solution, this is what I just tried and worked too.
df1.join(df1['name'].str.split(',',expand=True)).to_csv('results.csv',index=None)

Comment: I think your solution is better than mine. I have to look up the max number of commas by first transforming the resulting lists into their length. in your solution you just join.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
out = df.join(df['Name'].str.split(', ',expand=True).add_prefix('name_'))
```